# How to fix load lang.xml failed in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I try to open npp it shows configurator load lang.xml failed.what is the solution for this.and the logs are printed with non proper characters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/67128/notepad-is-unable-to-load-langs-xml-why) on StackExchange, can you try and check if it still works?

> Somehow, your `langs.xml` has errors in it. Perhaps while exploring
> various Notepad++ options you accidentally made unintended changes to
> it. That's what happened to me.
>
> Go to the installation folder for Notepad++ and rename `langs.xml` to
> `langs.xml.bad`. Then, in that same folder, find `langs.model.xml`, make a
> copy of it, and rename the copy to `langs.xml`. **DO NOT** simply rename the
> file or you will not have it available the next time you need it.
>
> also replace this file in the folder
> `C:\users\(user)\appdata\roaming\notepad++`
>
> You will want to then compare the `langs.xml` to `langs.xml.bad` and see
> if there is anything legitimate that you want back.
>
> If you are missing the `langs.model.xml` file, you can [download the
> current version from the svn repo](http://notepad-plus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/notepad-plus/trunk/PowerEditor/src/langs.model.xml?view=log).